# REDCap accepts only single conditional @HIDECHOICE

Tags: redcap

I'm using the following action tags in a single-answer multiple choice question to hide choices if certain conditions aren't met in a prior matrix question:

```
@IF([med_1]<>'3', @HIDECHOICE='1','')
@IF([med_2]<>'3', @HIDECHOICE='2','')
@IF([med_3]<>'3', @HIDECHOICE='3','')
```

It seems that only one of the `@HIDECHOICE` options is honored even when the conditions for all of them are met. E.g, if the answers for med_1, med_2, and med_3 are *all* unequal to 3, only choice 1 for the present question is hidden. Is there a way to set up independent display logic for each choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite right. Only the first @HIDECHOICE in a field is honoured. If there are multiple @HIDECHOICE action tags in various @IF() action tags, then only the first @HIDECHOICE that is encountered that is honoured. So in your case, if [med_1] = 3 an [med_2] = 1, then choice 2 would be hidden. The value of [med_3] is irrelevant as that @HIDECHOICE will not be executed.

You can pass multiple choices into a @HIDECHOICE though, with a comma-separated list, but as you can only reasonably use a single @HIDECHOICE, then you have to construct some pretty gnarly logic. With three variables to test in a binary sense, you have 2**3 terms to evaluate (minus 1, since you don't need a @HIDECHOICE where all three are equal to 3):

```
@IF([med_1]<>'3' AND [med_2]<>'3' AND [med_3]<>'3', @HIDECHOICE='1,2,3','')
@IF([med_1]<>'3' AND [med_2]='3' AND [med_3]<>'3', @HIDECHOICE='1,3','')
@IF([med_1]<>'3' AND [med_2]<>'3' AND [med_3]='3', @HIDECHOICE='1,2','')
@IF([med_1]='3' AND [med_2]<>'3' AND [med_3]<>'3', @HIDECHOICE='2,3','')
@IF([med_1]<>'3' AND [med_2]='3' AND [med_3]='3', @HIDECHOICE='1','')
@IF([med_1]='3' AND [med_2]<>'3' AND [med_3]='3', @HIDECHOICE='2','')
@IF([med_1]='3' AND [med_2]='3' AND [med_3]<>'3', @HIDECHOICE='3','')
```

Adding more conditions will exponentially raise the burden.

Unfortunately, @HIDECHOICE does not accept piping, otherwise you could use a @CALCTEXT field to generate the comma-separated list of choices to hide, say, [hidechoice], and then pipe it in with `@HIDECHOICE='[hidechoice]'`. This would turn an O(2^n) operation into an O(n) operation, but has not been implemented.

Comment: Jangari my actual use case is 30 choices, so this won't work for me, but probably useful for cases with a small number of choices.

Comment: Yep, that would be tough. There might be another way. What is it you need to achieve?

Comment: Jangari - we're having people answer whether or not they accomplished a list of 30 things. On the last page, I want to list the things they indicated accomplishing in a multiple-choice question and have them pick the most important one.

Comment: Okay, as a slightly different workaround, you could emulate this with a matrix of 30 radio fields, with a single choice in the matrix, and set it to 'ranking', which will allow only a single response per column (per the single column). Additionally, set branching logic on each row of the matrix so that it displays if the corresponding choice in the original list of 30 things was checked.

Comment: Jangari - yep, that works well enough for my purposes. Thanks so much!

Comment: I've submitted a request for this to our REDCap admin and they've forwarded it along, so we'll see if it turns up in the future.